# typemock threw InvalidCast exception

Tags: dependency-injection, typemock

I have following code snipped and I tried to test it using typemock but got InvalidCast exception.  ISomeClass is just an interface and SomeClass implements that interface.  UseOfSomeClass is another class which uses SomeClass and its constructor takes SomeClass as parameter.  I need to test UseOfSomeClass.  How do I inject a typemock fake object into a class constructor?

```
public interface ISomeClass
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do something!");
    }
}

public class UseOfSomeClass
{
    public SomeClass SomeClassProperty { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public UseOfSomeClass(SomeClass someClass)
    {
        SomeClassProperty = someClass;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        SomeClassProperty.DoSomething();

        IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Then test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UseOfSomeClassTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var fakeSomeClass = Isolate.Fake.Instance<ISomeClass>();

        var use = new UseOfSomeClass((SomeClass)fakeSomeClass);

        use.MyMethod();

        Assert.IsTrue(use.IsChecked);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be mocking `SomeClass` instead of `ISomeClass`?

Comment: Yes.  If I mock SomeClass, it works fine.  But why I shouldn't mock ISomeClass?  Or when should mock an interface and when mock a concrete class?

Comment: If the class constructor requires a `SomeClass`, you need to mock `SomeClass`. If it requires a `ISomeClass`, you need to mock `ISomeClass`. Normally, when you do dependency injection, you should prefer to change `UseOfSomeClass` to accept a `ISomeClass` in the constructor instead of `SomeClass`. Actually, you should not have the interface named similar to the class, it should represent a contract that the class implements.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: Yacoub is right you should mock SomeClass as it's the object that your c'tor requires, you will to mock it as a future instance like in the following way: **var fakeSomeClass = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<SomeClass>();**

Answer (score 0):

[Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/) allows you to mock concrete classes, so there's no need to fake ISomeClass in your test case. You can just fake SomeClass and send it as a parameter to the ctor.

```
[TestMethod, Isolated]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var fakeSomeClass = Isolate.Fake.Instance<SomeClass>();

    var use = new UseOfSomeClass(fakeSomeClass);

    use.MyMethod();

    Assert.IsTrue(use.IsChecked);
}
```